# Error in Eclipse, viewer filter class does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I'm working with Eclipse 4.6.3 and when I open a .java file I got the 2 following errors

> The org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters plug-in extension "org.eclipse.buildship.ui.packageexplorer.filter.gradle.subProject" specifies a viewer filter class which does not exist.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.buildship.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.buildship.ui.navigator.SubProjectViewerFilter.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.buildship.ui (73).

and

> The org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters plug-in extension "org.eclipse.buildship.ui.packageexplorer.filter.gradle.buildfolder" specifies a viewer filter class which does not exist.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.buildship.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.buildship.ui.navigator.BuildFolderViewerFilter.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.buildship.ui (73).

These errors are not blocking Eclipse, I can still create/edit/save/delete files.

Does someone know where it comes from ? and how to solve it ?

Comment: Something wrong with the Buildship for Gradle plugin by the look of it

Comment: Hmm okay and where do I configure that ?

Comment: I've looked at the plugin org.eclipse.buildship.ui and I didn't something that looks weird. Am I missing an import or a configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to reinstall (uninstall-restart-install) Buildship Gradle Integration.

Comment: Help-> Eclipse marketplace-> Search for Buildship Gradle. It will show as installed. Clock on it, it will show option to update. Update the plugin & restart eclipse. it worked for me.